# Adding measurement circuits to the singlet state circuit and want to create single circuit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, entanglement, measurement, quantum-circuit

I am trying to add the measurement of Alice and bob's circuit to the singlet circuit. Actually, I am trying to build the e91 protocol. But it is giving me an error like this.

```
circuits = []

for i in range(numberOfSinglets):
    circuitName = str(i) + ':A' + str(aliceMeasurementChoices[i]) + '_B' + str(bobMeasurementChoices)

    alice_circuit = aliceMeasurements[aliceMeasurementChoices[i]-1]
    bob_circuit = bobMeasurements[bobMeasurementChoices[i]-1]

    QuantumCircuit.append(circuitName, singlet & alice_circuit & bob_circuit)

    # add the created circuit to the circuits list
    circuits.append(circuitName)
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In[96], line 9
> 6 alice_circuit = aliceMeasurements[aliceMeasurementChoices[i]-1]
> 7 bob_circuit = bobMeasurements[bobMeasurementChoices[i]-1]
> ----> 9 QuantumCircuit.append(circuitName, singlet & alice_circuit & bob_circuit)
> 11 # add the created circuit to the circuits list
> 12 circuits.append(circuitName)
>
> File
> ~/anaconda3/envs/QC/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py:1276,
> in QuantumCircuit.append(self, instruction, qargs, cargs)    1273
> expanded_qargs = [self.qbit_argument_conversion(qarg) for qarg in
> qargs or []]    1274 expanded_cargs =
> [self.cbit_argument_conversion(carg) for carg in cargs or []]
> -> 1276 if self._control_flow_scopes:    1277     appender = self._control_flow_scopes[-1].append    1278     requester =
> self._control_flow_scopes[-1].request_classical_resource
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_control_flow_scopes'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.